# How to "join" in Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Say I have a `users` collection, `companies` collection, and `companyUserMemberships` collection. `users` and `companies` are independent from each other and `companyUserMemberships` has a user and company field (plus other metadata like their permission level). For example's sake, assume we want to CRUD "posts" into the company app.

Part that I can't figure out is how to do a validation with this. I want anyone in the company to read the "post", but not outside companies, but I also only want the user who posted to be able to update/delete.

Doesn't appear to be able to truly query so the best idea I've come up with so far is store list of user uids inside the company as a `map` type and that has the metadata and get rid of `companyUserMemberships` altogether. Something like this:

[image]

I'm just not sure if this is "correct". Nesting just feels incorrect but I'm not sure if that's just because I come from a SQL background.

Comment: in firebase rules, for this kind of a scenario I think you need to nest so that rule above the collection or id above the collection of the outside nested rule can be applied to the inside nested rule. You can research on that way.

Answer (score 1):

> I want anyone in the company to read the "post", but not outside
>   companies, but I also only want the user who posted to be able to
>   update/delete.

According to your question, I'm assuming that you have the following requirements:

1) User can create a post for a company and update/delete a post created by him/her.

Validations required for `Posts` collection:

1. `allow create:` Is user authenticated?
2. `allow update, delete:` Is user authenticated? Is the post created by the user?

2) Anyone in a company can read a post created for the company.

Validations required for `Posts` collection:

1. `allow read:` Is user authenticated? Does the user belong to the company of the post?

You can implement these validations without needing the `companyUserMemberships` collection using Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

I'm assuming the document created in the `posts` collection has information regarding the author of the post in a field `createdBy` and name of the company of the post in a field `company`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    //Get the user using uid
    function getUser() {
        return(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data);
    }

    //Check if user exists
    function isValidUser(user) {
    //Validate the necessary privileges 
        return (user != null);
    }

    // Check access for Posts
    match /posts/{postId} {
        // Any authorized user of a company can read posts for the company
        allow read: if ( isValidUser(getUser()) && resource.data.company == getUser().company)
        // Any authorized user can create a post
        allow create: if ( isValidUser(getUser()));

        // Any authorized user can update and delete his/her a post only
        allow update, delete: if ( isValidUser(getUser()) && request.resource.createdBy == getUser().uid);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.